# Javascript: axios: Batching Requests

Tags: javascript, batch-processing, axios

How to do batching requests using axios:

I have the following batch request

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=====1340674896===

--====1340674896===

GET /contacts/479038 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

--====1340674896===

GET /contacts/299430 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

--====1340674896===--
```

How to get the response using axios: I am trying the below

```
     const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=====1340674896==='
        }
     }
     axios.post('/batch',data,config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

how to pass the data which is

```
    --====1340674896===

GET /contacts/479038 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

--====1340674896===

GET /contacts/299430 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

--====1340674896===--
```

Comment: [Here is an example](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2009#issuecomment-597083839)